# Ubuntu goes black after changing the nvidia graphics driver

Tags: boot, nvidia, live-usb

I had changed the nvidia proprietary driver to 340 I guess and when rebooting the password login thing for the encrypted disk appears but no login screen after that. It goes grey and then black and nothing happens. I am currently on a bootable usb and I have did the try Ubuntu thing. I can access the disk files after I have entered the password. But how do I change the nvidia drivers from here? Like can I do that manually? And I want to recover without loosing any files. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried to boot into recovery (with networking)?  You will drop to a root shell prompt and you can reverse any changes you made.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Using grub menu. That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Yayy!! The problem has been solved. After logging in for the disk encryption I pressed esc key and was able to get into a terminal style login. From there I was able to change the nvidia driver and after reboot it worked like a charm. Thank you guys for the support and tips! Hope this will be helpful to someone. And sorry I'm a noobie at linux